# MySQL add data to an existing field

Tags: mysql, field, updates

I have a field `enq_id` - it currently contains numbers such as:

```
80081
414365
567
```

Now, I need to update the field in two ways, firstly I need to find out if any of the numbers are more than 6 characters long (there shouldn't be but I need to check).  I then need to set a character limit of 6 characters on that field and then, finally, add `0's` to the beginning of any `enq_id` that isn't 6 characters long to make it 6 characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following returns the result you're trying to achieve:

```
SELECT
    `enq_id`,
    IF(CHAR_LENGTH(`enq_id`) < 6,
        LPAD(`enq_id`,6,'0'),
        SUBSTRING(`enq_id`,1,6)
    ) AS 'result'
FROM `some_table`
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`enq_id`) != 6
```

Then using the following will update your table accordingly.

```
UPDATE `some_table`
SET `enq_id` = 
    IF(CHAR_LENGTH(`enq_id`) < 6,
        LPAD(`enq_id`,6,'0'),
        SUBSTRING(`enq_id`,1,6))
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`enq_id`) != 6
```

Note that the `SUBSTRING()` function deletes all the characters after the 6th character, and LPAD adds preceding zeros (in the above example) if needed, to each record.

---

**UPDATE:** For some reason I added an extra condition. The optimized code(s) should have been:

```
SELECT `enq_id`,LPAD(`enq_id`,6,'0') AS 'result'
FROM `some_table`
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`enq_id`) < 6
```

and

```
UPDATE `some_table`
SET `enq_id` = LPAD(`enq_id`,6,'0')
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`enq_id`) < 6
```

Comment: No problem. For some reason I added an extra condition for the records with length > 6. I'm updating the code.